# LEA instruction - How to transform into C language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I try to transform some piece of assembly in C language. I know that the LEA instruction stores an address into a specified register.

For example:

```
LEA EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP - 0x8]
```

In the stack address [EBP - 0x8], I have the value 00000003D (ollydbg shows it). 
If I assume that eax is a pointer and regard 00000003D as 61(decimal), then I try the following:

```
int value = 61;

int *eax = &value
```

Would you agree ? Yes or not? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LEA` instruction computes an address which in this case is a pointer to a local variable, so what you have written matches very closely.

Comment: hi, Dwayne. I dont know the syntax of (int *)61. Can you explain it to me? The second thing is:I wrote above that I have the value 61 in [EBP-0x8] . So, 61 is not the address.

Comment: (type)expression means "cast" the expression to this type. So in this case it means take the value 61 (which is an int) and forceably convert it to a pointer (basically just "close your eyes" and do it anyway). However, I misunderstood your question at first. Now I understand what you mean and your solution is right.